# Which form of punctuation is the most appropriate for this parenthetical?

Tags: punctuation, parentheticals

Which form of punctuation is the most appropriate for this parenthetical?

1. The strategy team is relatively new, the unit split from its parent
   group in early 2016, but their work is already well known.
2. The strategy team is relatively new (the unit split from its parent
   group in early 2016) but their work is already well known.
3. The strategy team is relatively new - the unit split from its parent
   group in early 2016 - but their work is already well known.

Does this even read well, or should it be rephrased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example two is the only grammatically correct option. The first example is a run-on sentence. The third example does not use hyphens correctly.

The phrase "but their work is already well known" refers to the fact that the team is new and has nothing to do with the split. So your parenthetical is "the unit split from its parent group in early 2016."

A nice rewrite might be:
"Being split from its parent group in early 2016, the strategy team is relatively new but their work is already well known."